# C/ C++ basic struct not working Visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, struct

I have 2 simple structs and one has array of the second one.

When accesing the second one my program crashes in visual studio but not in codeblocks.

So one line is not working and another one is.

Can somebody explain why?

```
    struct buffer {
    uint64_t size;
    void* data;

};

struct list_of_buffers {
    uint64_t number_of_buffers;
    bool* active_buffers;
    struct buffer* array_of_buffers;
}buffer_list;




void alloc_fun(int size){
   buffer_list.array_of_buffers = (struct buffer*)calloc(0, sizeof(struct buffer) * size);

   //this one makes my program crash
   buffer_list.array_of_buffers[0].data = NULL;    

   //this one doesnt
   struct buffer tmp = buffer_list.array_of_buffers[0];
   tmp.data = NULL;
   }
```

Can somebody explain please?

Comment: Please show a [mcve], including where and how you allocate memory for `buffer_list.array_of_buffers`

Comment: how so? what does then calloc do?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the code. Though you still don't show what inputs you give and what `id` is

Comment: ops i forgot change that id

Comment: Actually, `calloc(0, ` means you allocate space for 0 elements - which is still 0 (and you are therefore not allowed to access any element via `buffer_list.array_of_buffers[x]`)

Comment: ***When accesing the second one my program crashes in visual studio but not in codeblocks.*** Thankfully Visual Studio has a good debugger that you can get it to break into the debugger instead of just ending execution. That way you can see what line of code is the problem.

Comment: okej i just missread stuff on geeks for geeks about that zero. gotta learn maual, thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking `calloc` for a buffer of 0 elements:

```
 buffer_list.array_of_buffers = (struct buffer*)calloc(0, sizeof(struct buffer) * size);
```

what that returns is implementation defined [as per the docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3p.html):

> If the size of the space requested is 0, the
>   behavior is implementation-defined: the value returned shall be
>   either a null pointer or a unique pointer.

So my guess is that visual studio is returning a null pointer (thus the crash) while code blocks is not. I think this is what you want:

```
buffer_list.array_of_buffers = (struct buffer*)calloc(size, sizeof(struct buffer) );
```